# C++11 char16_t strstr and sprintf equivalent

Tags: c++, c++11, char16-t

Is there any equivalent function to strstr and sprintf for char16_t type?

Also, where could I find the remaining functions of char16_t?

Comment: The UTF-16 equivalent of strstr is [wcsstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcsstr/).  Here is the complete list: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcsstr/.  And here is a Must-Read link: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Beware: wide char are not UTF-16 on every systems. AFAIK, on Linux `wchar_t` is a 32 bits integral type.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - good point.  The link I cited tries to make clear that Unicode != UTF-16 != UCS-2 != char16_t (like 1990's era Windows NT or Java programming might have you believe).

Comment: One additional link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588302/why-isnt-wchar-t-widely-used-in-code-for-linux-related-platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are such functions.

If `sizeof(char16_t) == sizeof(wchar_t)` you could use the wide string functions like `wsprintf`

<sup>Caveat: `sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(int32_t)` on Linux!</sup>

And you can always use (in C++11) the [std::u16string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Perhaps you might consider using Qt5 [QChar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qchar.html) (almost like a `char16_t` in UTF16) and [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html). You'll only need to link `QtCore` for that. Then [QString::arg](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#arg) is similar (but not equivalent) to what `sprintf` can offer.

As I commented, float to string conversion is tricky. Perhaps some code from [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org) (free software, MIT license) could inspire you, and you might borrow some of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that I can implement strstr out of std::u16string. How to implement sprintf for char16_t out of this?

Comment: But I cannot link QtCore to my project due to some constraints.

Comment: Then you have to re-implement your `sprintf` like function.

Comment: That is what I did. But due to some limitation, I have not supported %f and %e format because I need floating point or double to string conversion. Can you give me good links to do this accurately?

Comment: No, I can't give links; it is tricky and hard to do right. Maybe some code from [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) could help you (MIT licensed free software).

Answer (score 0):

For strstr you can use `std::u16string_view::find` or even the C++23 `std::u16string_view::contains` if you're only interested in a boolean result.

```
const bool contains_world =
    std::u16string_view(u"Hello, World!").find(u"World") != std::u16string_view::npos;
```