# JNI jchar* to wchar* not working as expected

Tags: java, c++, string, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass a `java.lang.String` from Java to C++ but there seems to be a little mistake in the code encoding from java String to Windows WCHAR*.

On the Java side I have

```
public native void sendText(String text);
```

And on the C++ side

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_sendText(JNIEnv *env, jobject o, jstring text) {
    const jchar* _text = env->GetStringChars(text, FALSE);

    const WCHAR* txt = (const WCHAR*)_text;
    UINT32 len = (UINT32)wcslen(txt);
    IDWriteTextLayout* textLayout;
    DWriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(txt, len, textFormat, rect.right - x, rect.bottom - y, &textLayout);

    g->DrawTextLayout(D2D1::Point2F(x, y), textLayout, currBrush);
    env->ReleaseStringChars(text, _text);
}
```

I'm trying to send the String **test string: 00:00:00** but on the C++ side I'm getting things like **Àest string: 00:00:00** and **Ùest string: 00:00:00**. It seems like only the first character is failing to convert, I have the unicode charset selected in MSVS but I don't have a clue what's going wrong. I have searched around and other posts say a simple cast between jchar* and wchar_t* should be possible.

Comment: The second parameter to `GetStringChars` is a pointer; `nullptr` might be clearer than `FALSE`. (Although both are valid.)

Comment: How are you finding the value of the string on the C++ side? If you're printing it, how?

Comment: Well the reason I'm casting to WCHAR* is because I use the string to draw text on the screen using DirectWrite. `UINT32 len = (UINT32)wcslen(txt);
IDWriteTextLayout* textLayout;
DWriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(txt, len, textFormat, rect.right - x, rect.bottom - y, &textLayout);`

Comment: Try something simpler (eg call `MessageBoxW`) to verify the string. Or show some more code.

Comment: I added some more code

Comment: You should use `env->GetStringLength(text)` to get the length, rather than `wcslen` (the Java string may not be zero terminated). But I doubt that's your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert jstring to wchar\_t \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042/how-do-i-convert-jstring-to-wchar-t)

Comment: In theory, jchar and WCHAR are not the same (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7881134/192373). For some use cases the distinction is critical, but it does not explain the observed behavior

Comment: Do you see the first character incorrect in debugger?

Comment: when I try `MessageBox(..)` or `MessageBoxW(..)` the box doesn't show, but when I do `const WCHAR* _text = L"Test string here";
UINT32 len = (UINT32)wcslen(_text);
DWriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(_text, len, textFormat, rect.right - x, rect.bottom - y, &textLayout);` the string shows up fine.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: When I try the solution you linked it still shows the first character bugged.